# why does sae increment by .0312

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I was wondering why there isn't a 9/20" diameter bolt and then realized the bolt sizes start at what ever size, the next size is + 39/1250 of an inch. Is there any reason for this? Is there any place to find a 9/20" hardware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0.03125 = 1/32 (exactly). The USA (and the UK before metrication) had a long tradition of subdividing basic measurements by factors of 2. For example the standard sizes of drills are usually state in 32ths or 64ths of an inch. This principle was used for other measures as well as lengths - e.g. gallons, quarts, pints - and sometimes for larger measures as well as fractions - e.g. pecks (4 gallons) and bushels (8 gallons), or weight units like hundredweights (8 stones).

The decimal conversions are more convenient to use with modern measuring devices than fractions, but anything less than 0.1 thousandth of an inch is not of much practical significance.

The list of standard sizes has small enough increments that there would be no particular use for an "odd size" like 9/20" = 0.45 in, when there is already a standard size 7/16" = 0.4375 in. Most likely, this would just lead to confusion and accidental use of the incorrect size bolts, which could cause problems if the wrong replacements parts, or tools like wrenches, were under or over size.

Of course in some very specialized applications, bolts and other fasteners might be designed to *any* size to meet the required specification, if the cost of the parts is not a significant issue. Such parts are likely to be made from special materials, as well as in special sizes.

Standard metric bolt sizes are more straightforward, because the bolt diameters and head sizes are all integer numbers of millimeters.